# what is function of alert?

Tags: javascript, html

i'v been studied some code on javascript.. by the way i'm newbie :) . here's the question: what is a function of "alert" ?

```js
<html> 
<body>   
<h1>Counting rabbits</h1>   
<script>     
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) 
{       alert("Rabbit "+i+" out of the hat!")     }   
</script>    
<h1>...Finished counting</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to display an alert box

Comment: To help with your studies: MDN is a great resource. Here's their page about the alert function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: And just an SO tip - you received a number of downvotes because you could of easily researched this yourself. Its expected you dig in before asking the community.

Answer (score 2):

Let me google that for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Alert is a method on the global window object that provides access to a native notification utility.

```
window.alert("Hello world!");
```

It can be used for direct user notification (if you haven't implemented something "nicer"), or as an ungainly alternative to `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

The function of the `alert` function is to display an alert box, like this:
[image]

It is usually best to say `window.alert` instead of just `alert`.